# Find the best threshold for logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, binary-data, threshold

I am working on a customer purchase problem. I have 150 campaigns sent by email (or adds if you prefer), that I denote `C0`, `C1` ... `C149`. Moreover, for each user `i` :

- `Cj`= 0 if campaign `j` is NOT received by customer `i`,
- `Cj`= 1 if campaign `j` is received by customer `i`
- Sucess = 0 or 1 ( 0 if customer `i` did NOT order despite the reception of campaigns, and 1 otherwise)

I want to **find the number of campaigns to make a customer order a product**. I don't really know how to handle this problem and I'm starting to get into panic.

What I did :

- I performed a logistic regression and got the intercept and the coef for nb_campaigns:

```
X=np.array(data['nb_campaings']).reshape(-1,1)
y=data['sucess']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 5)

model1 = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced',random_state=0, multi_class='ovr', penalty='none', solver='newton-cg', n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)
#Print model parameters
preds = model1.predict(X_test)
params = model1.get_params()
print('Intercept: \n', model1.intercept_[0])
print('Coefficients: \n', model1.coef_[0][0])

Intercept: 
 -3.185764946987113
Coefficients: 
 0.6909684308864985
R-squared=0.32
```

- Then, I plotted the probability of sucess=1 VS the number of campaigns received, and I have the following graph :

```
intercept= model1.intercept_[0]
coef_nb_campaigns=model1.coef_[0][0]
probs=[]
for i in range(0,19):
    probs+=[1/(1+np.exp(-(intercept+i*coef_nb_campaigns)))]
sns.lineplot(range(0,19),probs)
sns.scatterplot(data=test_plot,x='X_test',y='y_test')
pd.DataFrame(probs)
plt.xlabel("Number of campaigns received")
plt.ylabel("Probability that Sucess=1")
```

[image]

It is more likely that Y=1  (threshold>=0.5) if I send at least 4 or 5 campaigns.
**Do you think it is enough to solve the problem ?**
I am skeptical, as these calculations are theoretical. Moreover, the R squared is very low (0.32), and not only that, a threshold of 0.5 leads to "bad" predictions (cf PR Curve bellow) : [image: precision-recall curve]

According to the PR curve, a threshold of 0.5 isn't that good (low precision) so it is better to choose a least a threshold of 0.83, but **I can I find the corresponding number of campaigns** ( that enable to have a probability >=0.83) ? Can I use the first plot and say we need at least 7 campaigns to have "good" predictions ?

Do not hesitate to warn me if there is a more appropriate method to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code (much seems to be cut off in your image; it's better to put that code directly into the question with the markup tool for code) whether you are modeling the total number of campaigns or 150 separate campaigns. Please edit the question to clarify, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. Logistic regression doesn't have cutoffs per se; in your case you might use the probability model to gauge the cost/benefit of a particular number of campaigns. That depends on how you want to _use_ the modeling results given those costs and benefits.

Comment: There are many similar Qs. Do [dome of this help?](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+treshold+logistic+regression)

Comment: Could you treat your threshold as a hyperparameter and tune it?

Comment: Hi Alberson. Unfortunately I can't. That was my idea at first and I've read that it is not a hyperparameter. That's why I plotted the PR curve for different threshold values to check how it affects my predictions.